# Instead of updating data in pivot table it insert new record in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.4

I am working with the laravel 5.4

I have created 3 tables:
**tickets**
**ticket_cc_users**
**users**.

The table **ticket_cc_users** works as a pivot table.

In the code below, i want to update my pivot table. However, when i run the update query, it inserts data into my database instead of updating it.

```
$ticket = Ticket::find($id);
$ticket->requester_id = $this->user['id'];
$ticket->type = $request->type;
$ticket->priority = $request->priority;
$ticket->subject = $request->subject;
$ticket->description = $request->description;
$ticket->status = $request->status;     
if($ticket->save())
{
    for($i=0;$i<count($request->cc_id);$i++)
    {
        $ticket->users()->attach($request->cc_id[$i]['id'],['ticket_id'=>$ticket->id]);
    }           
}
```

**Ticket model :**

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','ticket_cc_users');
}
```

**User model :**

```
public function tickets()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Tickets\Ticket','ticket_cc_users');
}
```

What should i do in order to my the code do what i want?

Comment: Can you show the relations in your Ticket and User model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **attach()** method will create a new record in your pivot table. To update an existing record:

```
$ticket->users()->updateExistingPivot($userID, $arrayOfColumnsYouWantToUpdate);
```

I'm not sure what yor `$request->cc_id` means, but in my example if you can set `$userID` to a ID of a user which you want to update and the next argument in the method `updateExistingPivot()` is an array of the columns in the pivot table which you want to update.

**EDIT**

If you want to update the users related to the ticket replace your for loop with this one:

```
$userIDs = [];

for($i=0;$i<count($request->cc_id);$i++)
{
    $userIDs[] = $request->cc_id[$i]['id'];
}

$ticket->users()->sync($userIDs);
```

The `sync()` method will delete all users which are no longer in your ticket and will add the new ones automatically.

Comment: I have tried as you said but it's not working. I have write `$ticket->users()->updateExistingPivot($request->cc_id[$i]['id'], ['user_id']);`  Here user_id is a column name. And `$request->cc_id` is a array of user_id.

Comment: The second argument needs to be like this `['key' => 'value']`, to me this looks like you want to update all the users related to this ticket, so check my edited answer.